# Proving two functions are equivalent without exactly the same hypotheses

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

First question post! Sorry for any inappropriate format in advance.

Trying to prove two versions of functions are the equivalent, I can't proceed after reaching this step. How can I solve this?

```
1 subgoal
a' : nat
Ha' : forall b : nat, version1 a' b 0 = version2 a' b 0
b' : nat
Hb' : version1 a' b' b' = version2 a' b' b'
______________________________________(1/1)
version1 a' (S b') (S b') = version2 a' (S b') (S b')
```

Comment: This is usually the place where you use specific properties of your functions. It's very hard to say what you should do without the definitions of `version1` and `version2`. Still, a good first step would be to simplify the goal by computation, (eg. using `simpl`) and see if what you get is easier to solve.

Answer (score 0):

As currently stated, this goal is incomplete, because we do not know what `version1` and `version2` are.  One may be tempted to think the statement should be true for any choices of `version1` and `version2`, but for some choices of these functions, the opposite is provable:

```
Definition v1 (a b c : nat) :=
    Nat.leb c 1.

Definition v2 (a b c : nat) :=
    Nat.ltb c 1.

Lemma counterexample :
  ~ (forall (version1 version2 : nat -> nat -> nat -> bool),
     forall a' : nat,
     forall Ha' : (forall b : nat, version1 a' b 0 = version2 a' b 0), 
     forall b' : nat,
     forall Hb': (version1 a' b' b' = version2 a' b' b'),
      version1 a' (S b') (S b') = version2 a' (S b') (S  b')).
Proof.
intros abs.
assert (v1 0 1 1 = v2 0 1 1).
  apply abs.
    auto.
  auto.
discriminate.
Qed.
```